# Make sure checkbox is checked before submitting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a simple "terms of use" checkbox set up and I want users to check it before submitting the form. I'm using the WordPress plugin "WP-Polls".

Here's what I've tried:

```
$('.wp-polls-form').submit(function() {
    if ($('input:checkbox', this).is(':checked')) {
        // everything is fine...
    } else {
        alert('Please agree to the Terms of Use.');
        return false;
    }
});
```

The HTML:

```
<form id="polls_form_1" class="wp-polls-form" action="/index.php" method="post">
    <p style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" id="poll_1_nonce" name="wp-polls-nonce" value="12a6404147"></p>
    <p style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="poll_id" value="1"></p>
    <div id="polls-1-ans">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" id="poll-answer-1" name="poll_1" value="1"></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="poll-answer-2" name="poll_1" value="2"></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="poll-answer-3" name="poll_1" value="3"></li>
    </ul>

    <label class="check-terms"><input type="checkbox">I am over 18 and I have read and understand the Terms of Use</label>

    <input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons" onclick="poll_vote(1);">
```

### Edit 1:

Updated it to this to include radio buttons:

```
//Make sure checkbox and radio are checked before submitting
$('.wp-polls-form').submit(function() {
    if ($('input:checkbox', this).is(':checked') &&
        $('input:radio', this).is(':checked')) {
        // everything is fine...
    } else {
        alert('Please agree to the Terms of Use.');
        return false;
    }
});
```

### Edit: 2

Thanks to @AnthonyGarcia. The buttons work exactly how I'd like them to, but the only problem is that the form does not submit.

For the submit button, I changed the type from `button` to `submit` and also got rid of `onclick="poll_vote(1);"`.

`<input type="submit" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons" />`

```
$(function() {
    window.poll_vote = function(num) {
        console.log(num);
    }
    
    $('.wp-polls-form').submit(function(e) {
        
        if (!$('input:radio', this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('Please pick a beat.');
            return false;
        }
        
        if (!$('input:checkbox', this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('Please agree to the Terms of Use.');
            return false;
        }
        
        poll_vote(1);
        
        return false;
    });
});
```

The live site can be seen [here](http://staging.keebs.com). The relevant section is the dark voting section on top.

### Edit: 3

Here is the function for `poll_vote()`. I got it from the `polls-js.dev.js` file in the plugin here: https://github.com/lesterchan/wp-polls

```
// When User Vote For Poll
function poll_vote(current_poll_id) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        if(!is_being_voted) {
            set_is_being_voted(true);
            poll_id = current_poll_id;
            poll_answer_id = '';
            poll_multiple_ans = 0;
            poll_multiple_ans_count = 0;
            if($('#poll_multiple_ans_' + poll_id).length) {
                poll_multiple_ans = parseInt($('#poll_multiple_ans_' + poll_id).val());
            }
            $('#polls_form_' + poll_id + ' input:checkbox, #polls_form_' + poll_id + ' input:radio, #polls_form_' + poll_id + ' option').each(function(i){
                if ($(this).is(':checked') || $(this).is(':selected')) {
                    if(poll_multiple_ans > 0) {
                        poll_answer_id = $(this).val() + ',' + poll_answer_id;
                        poll_multiple_ans_count++;
                    } else {
                        poll_answer_id = parseInt($(this).val());
                    }
                }
            });
            if(poll_multiple_ans > 0) {
                if(poll_multiple_ans_count > 0 && poll_multiple_ans_count <= poll_multiple_ans) {
                    poll_answer_id = poll_answer_id.substring(0, (poll_answer_id.length-1));
                    poll_process();
                } else if(poll_multiple_ans_count == 0) {
                    set_is_being_voted(false);
                    alert(pollsL10n.text_valid);
                } else {
                    set_is_being_voted(false);
                    alert(pollsL10n.text_multiple + ' ' + poll_multiple_ans);
                }
            } else {
                if(poll_answer_id > 0) {
                    poll_process();
                } else {
                    set_is_being_voted(false);
                    alert(pollsL10n.text_valid);
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert(pollsL10n.text_wait);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: did you keep your script in a dom ready handler

Comment: can you add a console statement in the submit handler to see whether it is getting called

Comment: what is happening in `poll_vote`

Comment: when you submit the vote is there a page reloading

Comment: can you remove `onclick="poll_vote(1);"` from the button and see whether the alert is coming.. then move `poll_vote(1);` to the `if` block in your code

Comment: another thing you can try is event delegation like `$(document).on('submit', '.wp-polls-form', function(){...})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61156/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-j82).

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Hope it helps. Thanks

```
 $('.wp-polls-form').submit(function() {
        var isCheckboxChecked = $("input[type*='checkbox']").filter(":checked");
        if (isCheckboxChecked) {
            // everything is fine...
        } else {
            alert('Please agree to the Terms of Use.');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is never called, because you are **not** submitting your form. You have to replace this:

```
<input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons" onclick="poll_vote(1);">
```

By something like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons">
```

Here is a fiddle with the modified code: http://jsfiddle.net/5st235fn/

Comment: Thanks for the 'submit' tip. Only problem I have now is that when I click a radio button, but don't click the checkbox, a popup comes up saying I need to agree, but when I click ok in the dialog box, it still continues submitting. I updated the JS as well which you can see in my updated post. You can check out the live site at http://staging.keebs.com. Is there any way to prevent the form from submitting if the user has not checked the checkbox? Also, I just noticed that if I click both a radio and checkbox buttons, I get the same message saying that I need to choose a poll answer.

Comment: I updated my fiddle there: http://jsfiddle.net/vj3ms5es/ I think it does what you want.

Comment: The radio/checkbox buttons seem to function perfectly now. Only thing is, the form doesn't get submitted. Previously, when the user clicked submit, the plugin (WP-Polls) loaded a new "thank you" div. I tried re-adding the `onclick` attribute like this but it's still not working: `<input type="submit" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons" onclick="poll_vote(1);"  />` Any ideas?

Comment: The line that disable the submit is `e.preventDefault()`, you can just remove it if you want the form to be really submitted.

Comment: I recommend you to not use onclick in a form when you are also binding onsubmit. Just add your function call in the submit function like I do in the fiddle.

Comment: I took off the `onclick` attribute from the submit button and also removed `e.preventDefault()` from the JavaScript. However, the form still isn't submitting. I updated the code in my original post.

Comment: Also, I posted the function for `poll_vote()` in my last edit in case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I love to replace submit buttons with simple buttons and then submit forms programatically (or POSTing their values with ajax). However, your have an `onclick="poll_vote(1);"` that we don't know what's doing, so this answer will just make a guess.

If there's a `poll_vote` and you really mean to call it, try adding this to the end

```
function poll_vote(param) {
    ... current code ...
    if ($('input:checkbox', '.check-terms').is(':checked')) {
        $('.wp-polls-form').submit();
    } else {
        alert('Please agree to the Terms of Use.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean post that at the end of the latest code in my post? By the way, I added the function for `poll_vote()` in the latest edit.